# Constant of integration use question.

Tags: calculus, integration

I get mixed up with what I can and can't do with the constant of integration $C$.

After integrating I have

$$-10\ln(y)=t+C.$$

What I did was: $$ \ln (y)=\frac{t}{-10} + C \implies y = e^{-\frac{t}{10}}+ C \implies y=Ce^{-\frac{t}{10}},$$

and using an initial condition solved for $ C $ at $ t = 0$. which was $ y(0)=30$, so $ C=30$.

However there should be an equilibrium value at $10$ which I'm not getting in this graph, so I must of mixed up some rule with the $C$.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean $\ln$ when you wrote $nl$.

You can basically do anything with the $C$, so long as it represents an *arbitrary constant value*.

So, you can write:
$$-10\ln y= t+C$$
$$\ln y= \frac{t}{-10}+\frac{C}{-10}$$
Now, note that some arbitrary constant divided by $-10$ is *still* an arbitrary constant.  Thus, we have:
$$\ln y= \frac{t}{-10}+C$$
$$y= e^{\frac{t}{-10}+C}$$
$$y= e^{\frac{t}{-10}}e^{C}$$

But, $e$ raised to an arbitrary constant is *also* an arbitrary constant.  Thus, you have:
$$y= Ce^{t/(-10)}$$

Using your initial conditions, we have:
$$y= 30e^{t/(-10)}$$

So, what you did *is* basically right. However, the equation you gave *does not* have an equilibrium solution (ever), as the derivative of an exponential as above is not equal to $0$ for any value of $t$.  So, my guess is you did something wrong before that...

Comment: Awsome thanks for your help!